# Vanilla JS Unexpected token A in JSON at position 141 json.parse()

Tags: javascript, json

I got data in JSON format that I need to remove special chars from, and then I need to make array of objects out of them.

```
const e = [{
            "response_code": 0, "results": [
                {
                    "category": "Entertainment: Cartoon & Animations",
                    "type": "multiple",
                    "difficulty": "medium",
                    "question": "What year was the Disney&#039;s film &quot;A Goofy Movie&quot; released in Berkley&#039;s?",
                    "correct_answer": "1995",
                    "incorrect_answers": ["1999", "2001", "1997"]
                },

                {
                    "category": "Entertainment: Television",
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "difficulty": "medium",
                    "question": "Like his character in &quot;Parks and Recreation&quot;, Aziz Ansari was born in South Carolina.",
                    "correct_answer": "True",
                    "incorrect_answers": ["False"]
                },]
        }]
        const data = [];
        data.push(...e[0].results);


        function decode(data) {
            console.log(data);
            let str = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
            console.log(str)
            let s = str.replace(/&quot;/g, '"').replace(/&#039;/g, "'");
            console.log(s)
            console.log(JSON.parse(s));
        }

        decode(data);
```

My replace() function works, however when I try to parse() the data back it throws error Unexpected token A in JSON at position 141.

Comment: Because your JSON is invalid - it has a trailing `,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not replace &quote; with `"` when you process the json string, you should use `\\"`.

`let s = str.replace(/&quot;/g, '\\"').replace(/&#039;/g, "'");`

```js
const e = [{
    "response_code": 0, "results": [
        {
            "category": "Entertainment: Cartoon & Animations",
            "type": "multiple",
            "difficulty": "medium",
            "question": "What year was the Disney&#039;s film &quot;A Goofy Movie&quot; released in Berkley&#039;s?",
            "correct_answer": "1995",
            "incorrect_answers": ["1999", "2001", "1997"]
        },

        {
            "category": "Entertainment: Television",
            "type": "boolean",
            "difficulty": "medium",
            "question": "Like his character in &quot;Parks and Recreation&quot;, Aziz Ansari was born in South Carolina.",
            "correct_answer": "True",
            "incorrect_answers": ["False"]
        },]
}]
const data = [];
data.push(...e[0].results);


function decode(data) {
    let str = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
    let s = str.replace(/&quot;/g, '\\"').replace(/&#039;/g, "'");
    console.log(JSON.parse(s));
}

decode(data);
```

Comment: Sure this lets me parse this but when you console.log() this it returns: "question": "Like his character in \"Parks and Recreation\", Aziz Ansari was born in South Carolina.", ....

there is a problem with \" string \" .... later in code I use function that matches answer user clicked on with answer that is in data variable.... however user is clicking on <li> answer </li> where it shows properly rendered, but in data variable I have these \" \" , and then my match function just doesnt work

I need to have equal li.innerText with data[0].answer strings

Comment: Well, I think you need modify match function to replace \\" with your &quot; back to make it equal.

Comment: Yea, probably... Tought it would be easier to remove these special chars as soon as I get data from API and then start working with them but, probably not. Anyways thank you!

Comment: I think you need to use this function `function decodeHtml(html) { var txt = document.createElement("div"); txt.innerHTML = html; return txt.innerText; }` to put your data to decode it. like `decodeHtml("Like his character in &quot;Parks and Recreation&quot;, Aziz Ansari was born in South Carolina.")`. In this way, you don't need to use replace to process your jsonstring data. Just decode both, then compare them directly. It's also feasible.

Comment: it returned [object Object],[object Object]..... I used let a = decodeHtml(data) ... body of function Ive just copied

Comment: I mean use `decodeHtml` before you put it into your <li></li>. With decodeHtml, you don't need to decode your data like `decodeHtml(data)` or `decode(data)`. `decodeHtml` is decode the string not object.